# How can I iterate through the wordsearch in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to make a wordsearch that **return the starting row, starting column, ending row and ending column of the word that has been found in the wordsearch** where the word is extracted from my list of strings where I call it 'words' here. I'm trying to find the horizontal match first, this is what I've tried but I'm stuck.

```
  def horizontal(labels, words):
            puzzle_word = []
            rows = labels.shape[0] # 15
            cols = labels.shape[1] # 15
        
            length = len(words)
            word = 0 # initialize word where word will be extracted from words 
    
        # replacing all the whitespaces:
            for line in labels:
                line = line.replace(' ', '')
                line = line.strip()
                if len(line) = 0:
                    for line in labels:
                        line = line.replace('\n', '')
                        line = line.lower()
                        words.append(line)
                        words = [x.upper() for x in words]
                        words = sorted(words)
    
        # iterate through the entire words list & extracting the words 1 by 1
            while word < length:
                for row in range(rows):
                    for column in range(columns):
                        character = labels[row][col] 

        # if the starting character matches with a word in the 2-D grid/array puzzle (called labels)
        # and width of all the columns of the grid - the character column to make sure the word will fit and not go over the column size
                        if word[0] == character and len(word) <= (cols-col):

        # how can I implement then look for the next character of the word and see if it matches the next character in the grid on the next column since we are finding horizontally now.
```

**Like maybe:**

```
  for index in word:
          while index < len(word):
           index += 1
                    ......................
```

Example of given file I'm using, where the grid is supposed to be in a form of a 2-D numpy grid array:

```
    J H C A T E H U C Y M J A L Q # cat is here
    N Q Q H K C B V T E X U F A E
    W O T A X E J K G N B P V M D
    C H C O U I R D P O F X X Z B
    Q M F R C P L P B H X K S L S
    H L I E A R F C Q V O H M D D
    K V F V P E A S Y Q P Z O J L
    H K Z N L T V G P C N G H D L
    R R Z V B S H D S M X Y T L B
    N A E L E P H A N T I S D N A # elephant is here
    O Y F D O G W E I L P X J R Z # dog is here
    Y D F C R W O S A U Z Y O T W
    K H M E E A L N C C G X L F B
    L Z F F S K Q I E L A R S S B
    X Z O H P D M J W Y C V D P A
   
words: ['cat', 'dog', 'elephant']
```

Comment: Can you not use built-in functions?

Answer (score 0):

Split the string. The common delimiter between words in a string is space. The split returns an array. Each element in the array is a word.
Use for loop to iterate over the words present in the array.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution that might help you get started.

```py
import numpy as np

labels = """
J H C A T E H U C Y M J A L Q
N Q Q H K C B V T E X U F A E
W O T A X E J K G N B P V M D
C H C O U I R D P O F X X Z B
Q M F R C P L P B H X K S L S
H L I E A R F C Q V O H M D D
K V F V P E A S Y Q P Z O J L
H K Z N L T V G P C N G H D L
R R Z V B S H D S M X Y T L B
N A E L E P H A N T I S D N A
O Y F D O G W E I L P X J R Z
Y D F C R W O S A U Z Y O T W
K H M E E A L N C C G X L F B
L Z F F S K Q I E L A R S S B
X Z O H P D M J W Y C V D P A
""".strip()

lines = np.array([line.split(' ') for line in labels.split('\n')])
words = ['cat', 'dog', 'elephant']

# horizontal matches
matches = []
for row, line in enumerate(lines):

    line = ''.join(line).lower()
    for word in words:
        if  (col := line.find(word)) >= 0:
           matches.append([word, (row, row), (col, col + len(word) - 1)])
    
print(matches) # word, (start row, end row), (start col, end col)
```

The idea is to view each line as a string and then do substring matching. For vertical matches, you can just transpose the array.

Comment: Thank you, however the return type if it is required to be in the form of a list of 4 digit tuples like (start_row, start_col, end_row, end_col) , one for each word in the format. Do I just do matches.append([row, row, col, col + len(word) -1)]) instead? Because I will be calling this horizontal function in another find_words function to return the position of the word on the word search puzzle.

Comment: Yes, that would yield the match in your desired format.

Comment: hey I have a question, if I want to print out the words found on the 2-D grid of classified letters, how can I print it out? Like in my find_words function it takes a parameter of the grid (labels), the words (words) and the model (dictionary) in which I trained my data set as the grid is taken from a picture. I tried doing "print horizontal(labels, words)" to try in the find_words function but it didn't seem to work. Or am I supposed to print it out in my horizontal (find horizontal) function and return the data after calling the horizontal function in my find_words function instead?

Comment: Also one more thing, it doesn't seem to let me use the strip() function in my horizontal funciton, like I tried labels.strip() where my labels is basically one of the parameters of the horizontal function as above which takes the 2-D grid numpy ndarray. But it gave me an error saying that 'numpy.ndarray' has no attribute 'strip'

Comment: `strip` can only be called on a string and removes white spaces at the start and end of a string. you dont need it anymore if you already have an array.